# Get Product Collection Containing In-Stock Products Only

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, product-collection, collection-filtering

There may be a simple answer to this, but I can't find it. I'm trying to retrieve a product collection, **excluding** products that are enabled, but out of stock.

I've tried the following approach, but this kicks out an error:

```
$productIds = array('3','4','9');

$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect(
        array('name', 'image', 'price')
    )
    ->addIdFilter($productIds)
;

$this->_productCollection = Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')
    ->addInStockFilterToCollection( $productCollection )
;
```

The following error occurs:

```
PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getTypeInstance() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Abstract.php on line 117
```

**app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Abstract.php:117** has the following method:

```
/**
 * Retrieve url for add product to cart
 * Will return product view page URL if product has required options
 *
 * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
 * @param array $additional
 * @return string
 */
public function getAddToCartUrl($product, $additional = array())
{
    // line 117:
    if (!$product->getTypeInstance(true)->hasRequiredOptions($product)) {
        return $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product, $additional);
    }
    $additional = array_merge(
        $additional,
        array(Mage_Core_Model_Url::FORM_KEY => $this->_getSingletonModel('core/session')->getFormKey())
    );
    if (!isset($additional['_escape'])) {
        $additional['_escape'] = true;
    }
    if (!isset($additional['_query'])) {
        $additional['_query'] = array();
    }
    $additional['_query']['options'] = 'cart';
    return $this->getProductUrl($product, $additional);
}
```

Is there a simple way to filter a collection to get only products that are in stock? Obviously I know about `isSaleable()` inside the loop. Thanks.

Comment: You're quoting the wrong method, fixing...

Comment: And judging from that, this goes wrong in your template, not in the code you pasted. So how do you loop through your collection and are you sure the call is failing *inside* your loop? Not some stray `$this->getAddToCartUrl($product)` outside of it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To answer the question. You would use this (not very different than your version):

```
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'image', 'price'))
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED));

Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')
    ->addInStockFilterToCollection($productCollection);

$this->_productCollection = $productCollection;
```

But I don't know exactly what causes your error, because it seems related to the fact that the `getSubmitUrl`/`getAddToCartUrl` product param is boolean false, and not to the collection per se.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer to the original question, thx newermind.

Comment: I'm afraid that it doesn't help for configurable products, since it will join cataloginventory_stock_item using the configurable product stock info, witch is incorrect, considering that Magento uses simple products to say if it is available or not.

Comment: Great that solve my problem

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a day late and a dollar short, but instead of doing all this second-step work, you can simply join the `cataloginventorystock_stock_status` table to your collection select():

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->join('cataloginventory_stock_status', 'cataloginventory_stock_status.product_id = e.entity_id', array('stock_status'));
$collection->getSelect()->where("`cataloginventory_stock_status`.`stock_status` = 1");
```

You can do this in conjunction with additional join() or where() clauses.
Hope it helps you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Newermind answered the original question correctly; my thanks to him. For future adventurers, here's what was wrong with my code. Special thanks to Melvyn for his help.

### Problem

From my code in the question, `$this->_productCollection` contains an *object*. When we iterate over that object in the view, the `$_product` variable is an *array*.

```
$_products = $this->_productCollection;

foreach ( $_products as $_product ) {
    echo gettype( $_product ); // <-- returns type [array]
}
```

The method at `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Abstract.php:117` (ultimately) calls `getTypeInstance()`. That method is expecting an *object*, specifically an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`.

In the view, I was calling `$this->getSubmitUrl($_product)` inside the foreach loop:

```
$_products = $this->_productCollection;

foreach ( $_products as $_product ) {
    echo $this->getSubmitUrl( $_product );
}
```

`getSubmitUrl()` is a method of `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract`, line 115. On line 123 it calls `getAddToCartUrl()`, which calls `getTypeInstance()` and that is expecting an *object*. Problem was, I was handing it an *array*.

Simple OOP principle, but I guess I was too tired to see it. Thx all for the help.

### The Solution

So, unfortunately the `addInStockFilterToCollection` method returns an **inventory** stock object - not what I was after. I need a **product collection** of *in-stock* products.

Also, the `addInStockFilterToCollection` method only works with a `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Link_Product_Collection` collection.

So, how to get the collection? My approach was as follows:

1. Get a collection of in-stock products.
2. Create an ID array from the result set.
3. Get the product collection, using the ID's from the in-stock results.

Here's the code:

```
$inStockProductIds = array();

$inStockCollection = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock')
    ->getItemCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('is_in_stock', 
        array( 'eq' => 1 )
    )
    ->addFieldToFilter( 'entity_id', 
        array( 'in' => array ('1', '2') )
    )
;

if ( $inStockCollection) {
    foreach ($inStockCollection as $stockProduct) {
        $inStockProductIds[] = $stockProduct->getId();
    }
}

$this->_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect(
        array('name', 'image', 'price')
    )
    ->addIdFilter( $inStockProductIds )
    ->setPageSize( 2 )
    ->load();
;

return $this->_productCollection;
```

That returns a product collection, only containing in-stock products. It's a bit heavy, but it works. I'd appreciate any improvements on this. Thanks.

Comment: why not just do something like: `$collection = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection() ... ; Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($col);` notice I don't do anything with the return value, but the collection gets updated to have instock filters on it.