# Filter products (out of stock) with xml

Tags: xml, filter

I found this code in a xml file:

```
<action method="setAvailableProducts">
      <value helper="mmartinovic_productlist/getAvailableOrders"></value>
</action>
```

Is there a similar way to filter products that are out of stock (by default I have to show all the products, regarding if in stocks or not)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a custom extension (looks like this one: [Mmartinovic_Productlist](https://github.com/Marko-M/Mmartinovic_Productlist)).
As far as I can see, this extension does not provide this functionality (look into `app/code/community/Mmartinovic/Productlist/Helper/Data.php`).

You can use a collection for this, as described [in this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18132/get-product-collection-containing-in-stock-products-only/18142).