# How to show only in stock products?

Tags: magento-1.9, cataloginventory

I am using product collection in my custom phtml  file I try to add filter only show in stock product but it will not work

**My code :**

```
$currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
$catId =47;
$last = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 days'));
$first = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-365 days'));
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId)
             ->getProductCollection()
             ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // add all attributes - optional
             ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1) // enabled
             ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4) //visibility in catalog,search
             ->setPageSize(8)
             ->addAttributeToFilter('updated_at', array(
                        'from' => $first,
                        'to' => $last,
                        'date' => true,
                        )); 
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');

 ?>
```

Comment: Please review https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/18142/2443

Answer (score 2):

I can see that your code does not contain any stock filter you can use this bit of code on the collection

```
$oCollection = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('is_in_stock',0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Below Query

$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'image', 'price'))
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED));

Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')
    ->addInStockFilterToCollection($productCollection);

$this->_productCollection = $productCollection;
```

Refrence->[Get Product Collection Containing In-Stock Products Only](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18132/get-product-collection-containing-in-stock-products-only)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a collection who display products just who have One minimum quantity (1) and **Not out of stock**.

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
         ->getCollection()
         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
         ->joinField('qty',
                     'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                     'qty',
                     'product_id=entity_id',
                     '{{table}}.is_in_stock=1',
                     'left')
         ->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array("gt" => 1))
         ->setCurPage(1) // limit to one page
         ->setPageSize(50); //limit to 50 products

    foreach($productCollection as $product) { 
        if($product->getTypeId() == 'simple')
            echo $product->getName().'<br>';
            echo $product->getProductUrl().'<br>';
            // you can get the other data ...
    }
```

Comment: @Ak Jh Please accept the answer that you found helful

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

You can change setting from admin panel.

For that goto your admin panel and **System -> Configuration**

Select **Inventory** tab under **CATALOG** menu.

Expand **Stock options** tab and set **Display Out of Stock Products** to **No**.

This may be help.